# luabind and java

Tags: java, lua

I'd like to expose Java classes to Lua etc.
For C/C++ there is luabind project. But I have not found anything like that for Java.
Is there any similar project to luabind for Java?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some available for JAVA too. Here:

- [LuaJava](http://www.keplerproject.org/luajava/)
- [jnaLua](https://github.com/dafrito/jna-lua)
- [jnLua](http://code.google.com/p/jnlua/)

Comment: Thank you. Which of them provide easy class binding like luabind: [link](http://www.rasterbar.com/products/luabind/docs.html#binding-classes-to-lua) Which one use similar syntax? (I need to rewrite C++ program with luabind to Java ...).

Comment: Again, I insist on a similar syntax with LUABIND, not with LUA only! Which one is the best?

Comment: @Petr I haven't used any of them myself. It'd be better if you read all their documentation and chose accordingly.

Comment: Thank you, I hoped someone else have read all of them and could be able to recommend the beset choice. I am looking right now on [link]http://luaj.org